# Retrieve files from URLs and save those with correct extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a simple Python based utility which can get all the download URLs from a web page and download the content. I found several methods of doing this and the best I found was "urllib". But unfortunately the problem with me is I can't save those with the proper extensions as the URLs look like below,

`http://example.com/2w3xa75`

But the content can be in different formats i.e. .mp3, .ogg etc.

How can I identify the type and save these contents with the correct extension.

Comment: You could try using [urllib.request.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)

Comment: You can convert the response header `Content-Type` to the correct extension assuming it is set accordingly to the file type and not octet-stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html),

The idea is to extract `Content-Type` HTTP header and ask to `mimetypes` to guess related extension.

I will use this question's URL as example (it doesn't provide extension)

```
import requests
import mimetypes

query = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488909/retrieve-files-from-urls-and-save-those-with-correct-extension')
content_type = query.headers['Content-Type']

print(mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type.split(';')[0]))
```

Output:

```
.html
```

A `Content-Type` header is like: `'text/html; charset=utf-8'`, but only the first part (`text/html`) is expected by [`mimetypes.guess_extension`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_extension), that's why I splitted it.

Comment: It seems it is working. But the problem is the extension I'm getting. I'm getting an output as .exe. But if I click on the link the download is a different one (e.g. .mp3) One thing I know for sure is the target site has developed with Microsoft technologies. Any idea?

Comment: Well, you will have to give me url you are trying to crawl because I can not do anything without

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the correct way to get that done. But unfortunately my problem is different. This funny web i'm testing seems executing an .exe to start download. Which makes it impossible to get the file type from "mimetype"